# ObservableCollection RemoveAt can't remove selecteditem in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have two datagrid's in my project and I wanto to move element from first datagrid to second one, and remove it from the first.
As far as copying works great i can't remove selected item from first datagrid.
Both datargids are binded with observablecollection

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       productionplan.Add(lstorder.SelectedItem as OrderItem); //creates a copy in second datagrid
       orderedlist.RemoveAt(lstorder.SelectedIndex); //should remove from first datagrid
    }
```

it throws exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" 
I have no idea why... 

Thansk for help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can do this,

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       productionplan.Add(lstorder.SelectedItem as OrderItem); 
       orderedlist.Remove(OrderItem);  
    }
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunetly it doese'nt work. If i set RemoveAt to a constant value ex. orderedlist.Remove(0); it works, except  when first row is selected. Only then the exception is thrown

Comment: @kasperro is it possible to give team viewer?

Comment: @kasperro try adding a null check before removing